# Efficient "window-select" array blocks?

Tags: arrays, matlab, select

Suppose I have the following array:

```
x = [a b
     c d
     e f
     g h
     i j];
```

I want to "swipe a window of two rows" progressively (one row at a time) along the array to generate the following array:

```
y = [a b c d e f g h
     c d e f g h i j];
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? I don't want to use `cellfun` or `arrayfun` or `for` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can do this using simple indexing:

```
x =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9    10

y = x.';                      %% Transpose it, for simplicity
z = [y(1:end-2); y(3:end)]    %% Take elements 1:end-2 and 3:end and concatenate them
z =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

You can do the transposing and reshaping in a simple step (see Suever's edit), but the above might be easier to read, understand and debug for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

[`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) is going to be your best bet here if you have the Image Processing Toolbox.

```
x = [1 2
     3 4
     5 6
     7 8];

im2col(x.', [1 2])
%   1     2     3     4     5     6
%   3     4     5     6     7     8
```

If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can also easily do this with built-ins.

```
reshape(permute(cat(3, x(1:end-1,:), x(2:end,:)), [3 2 1]), 2, [])
%   1     2     3     4     5     6
%   3     4     5     6     7     8
```

This combines the all rows with the next row by concatenating a row-shifted version along the third dimension. Then we use `permute` to shift the dimensions around and then we reshape it to be the desired size.

Comment: im2col is the way to go if you have the toolbox =) +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to solve it for a generic case of selecting `L` rows per window -

```
[m,n] = size(x) % Store size

% Extend rows by indexing into them with a progressive array of indices 
x_ext = x(bsxfun(@plus,(1:L)',0:m-L),:);

% Split the first dim at L into two dims, out of which "push" back the 
% second dim thus created as the last dim. This would bring in the columns 
% as the second dimension. Then, using linear indexing reshape into the 
% desired shape of L rows for output.
out = reshape(permute(reshape(x_ext,L,[],n),[1,3,2]),L,[])
```

Sample run -

```
x =                  % Input array
     9     1
     3     1
     7     5
     7     8
     4     9
     6     2
L =                  % Window length
     3
out =
     9     1     3     1     7     5     7     8
     3     1     7     5     7     8     4     9
     7     5     7     8     4     9     6     2
```